# Certificate Authority (CA) warning keeps popping up

Tags: certificate

Security Warning

You are about to install certificate from a certificate authority (CA) claiming to represent:

Titanium Root Certificate Authority

Etc.....

Then a Thumbprint very long number

I have no idea what this Titanium Root Certificate Authority CA is or how it got on my Windows 10 laptop or why it keeps wanting to install on my laptop.

I googled it and nothing at all shows up?

Do I have some sort of virus or malware?

[installed programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkeZM.png)

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMtXt.jpg)

Comment: It is not malware it was installed when you installed your Trend Micro security product.  You must have enabled the security feature that scans HTTPS traffic.  You can either disable the feature or uninstall the product.

Comment: That is the problem. I have no Trend Micro security product so I have nothing to uninstall. Could another program be installing this "Trend Micro" security product?

Comment: No;  The certificate is only installed Trend Micro software.  If you want to supply specific information about the certificate, show a screenshot of your installed programs, basically provide specific detailed information in order to answer your question

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me figure this out. I have added the information to my original post above. As you can see I don't use Windows 10 for a lot of things but I have two programs, Lutron and URC that only run on Windows 10 so that is why I keep it on my Laptop and dual boot between Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> I googled it and nothing at all shows up?

My research indicates the certificate belongs to [Titanium-Web-Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy)

> I have no idea what this Titanium Root Certificate Authority CA is or how it got on my Windows 10 laptop or why it keeps wanting to install on my laptop.  Do I have some sort of virus or malware?

You do not have malware currently installed.  You currently have an application which is designed to use the [Titanium-Web-Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy) framework.  If you trust the application using the framework then you should install the root certificate.  If you do not trust the application using the framework then you should uninstall the software.

Titanium Web Proxy is described as the following:

> A lightweight HTTP(S) proxy server written in C#.